# impl.ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer: Status for: {file-path}is 404

Tags: java, indexing, solr, solrj, behemoth

I want to index my a corpus using solr.
To create a sequence file, I used the following command:

```
./behemoth -i file://path/to/my/file/where/the corpus/is/located -o /user/user-name/file-to-which-the-putput-is-stored
```

After this I gave the following command for indexing:
./behemoth solr /user/user-name/pTH-to-which-output-is-stored-in-previous-command http://localhost:8983/solr

But its is giving the following error:

```
15/06/04 11:51:07 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local183059797_0001 running in uber mode : false  
15/06/04 11:51:07 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%  
15/06/04 11:51:08 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner:   
15/06/04 11:51:08 INFO impl.ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer: Status for: file:///usr/local/ASR/data/Corpus/en_TheTelegraph_2001-2010/telegraph_2007-2010/telegraph_1st_oct_2007_to_31st_dec_2007/foreign/1071015_foreign_story_8435523.utf8 is 404  
15/06/04 11:51:08 ERROR impl.ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer: error
java.lang.Exception: Not Found
```

I am unable to figure out the issue as the above mentioned file exists on that path. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Just found your question, best to ask on the DigitalPebble mailing list or open an issue on GitHub.

I don't think the problem is related to the content of the input. Looks more like it can't connect to SOLR.

Also you've imported a corpus of documents but no text or metadata have been extracted as part of the import. You should run the Tika module on your input first.